# Problem connect Android Studio-MySQL using JDBC (Error : java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.)

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I want create a connection between android studio and MySql.

Version of MySQL = MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Version of MySQL connector = mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar

Name of my database = testandroid

I already added the connector to my project

I got the Error : java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

Code :

```
private Connection getConnection(){
        Connection con;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testandroid?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=GMT","root","");
            return con;
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error ************************"+e);
            return null;
        }
    }


    private ArrayList<User> getUserList()
    {
        ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection connection = getConnection();


        String query = "Select pseudo FROM `users` where userID="+1;
        Statement st;
        ResultSet rs;

        try{
            st =  connection.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            User user ;
            while (rs.next())
            {
                user = new User(rs.getString("pseudo"));
                userList.add(user);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return userList;
    }


    private void showData(){

        ArrayList<User> list = getUserList();

        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){

            test.setText(list.get(i).getPseudo());
            test.setText("fnpvrpogn");

        }

    }
```

The Error

```
I/System.out: Error ************************java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.sql.Statement java.sql.Connection.createStatement()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.testjdbc.MainActivity.getUserList(MainActivity.java:54)
W/System.err:     at com.example.testjdbc.MainActivity.showData(MainActivity.java:73)
W/System.err:     at com.example.testjdbc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: The MySQL Connector/J 8.0.x driver does not work on Android. Also, you really should use JDBC on mobile devices, instead build a ReST service to mediate between your app and the database.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for your answer, but it's more safe to do JDBC and ReST service or use PHP ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. Write your ReST service in the language you're comfortable in, be it Java, PHP, Node.js, C#, whatever. The point is that 1) recent JDBC drivers don't work at all under Android, because they're likely using Java features or classes not present on Android, 2) direct database connections from mobile devices are likely to be slow, and 3) direct database connections from mobile devices is not very secure.

Comment: Oh alright thank you very much, for me it's PHP. But I using "Volley" in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

For software running on an Android device or emulator, `localhost` *is* the Android device or emulator. Most likely, your MySQL instance is not running on your Android device or emulator.

If you are running your app on an Android device, you need to use the IP address or host name of the machine running MySQL.

If you are running your app on an emulator, and MySQL is running on the same computer as is the emulator, use `10.0.2.2` as the address instead of `localhost`.

---

Also, please note that JDBC is not designed for use from mobile devices, from a reliability and security standpoint. Please consider doing something else, such as having your app talk to a Web service, which in turn talks to the database.

Comment: Okay thank you so much. But what "web service" mean?

Comment: It's not working, but I will continue to search